# Prolog recursion head and tail

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have to query a database to find the siblings of children who have at least two other siblings as well as printing the names of their parents.

This is what I've got so far:

```
queryQuestion3(Year,FatherName,MotherName):-
      family(person(FatherName,_,_,_),
             person(MotherName,_,_,_),
             [person(Name,Surname,date(_,_,Year),_),_,_|_])
   ;  family(person(FatherName,_,_,_),
             person(MotherName,_,_,_),
             [_,person(Name,Surname,date(_,_,Year),_),_|_])
   ;  family(person(FatherName,_,_,_),
              person(MotherName,_,_,_),
             [_,_,person(Name,Surname,date(_,_,Year),_)|_]).
```

This works, and it gives me the parent's names, but it only gives me the first three siblings and I have to deal with families larger than that without hardcoding.
I can imagine that the answer will use recursion, starting from the first sibling and iterating over them until you get to the last one, the base case, and then moving on to the next family, but I'm new to Prolog and wouldn't be very sure how to use tail and head recursion effectively to achieve this.

*** Update #2 ***

Thanks for the reply.
Here is the code now.

```
queryQuestion3(Year,FatherName,MotherName):-
   family(person(FatherName,_,_,_),person(MotherName,_,_,_), Children),
   member(person(_,_,date(_,_,Year),_), Children).
```

Comment: `family(person(FatherName,_,_,_),person(MotherName,_,_,_), Children), member(person(_,_,date(_,_,Year),_)`  BTW, `Name` and `Surname` are of no relevance to you!

Comment: ... And in your problem statement you do not mention the `Year` at all.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that I didn't mention I have to include the year of birth of all the siblings as well as the names of its parents. 

Thanks for noticing Name and Surname!

Your code is very helpful and it does list all the siblings' year of birth and all the parents' names, but it now includes all those families who have two children of fewer. I keep getting an infinite loop whenever I try to change it. The new code is shown above.

Comment: I do not see where there should be an infinite loop. Probably your data is inconsistent.

Comment: Add the goal `Children = [_,_,_|_]` to restrict to 3 or more

Comment: The code is working perfectly now!
Thanks very much!